# mysql avg length of a date squence

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a report i'm trying to figure out, but I would like to do it all with in a SQL statement instead of needing to iterate over a bunch of data in script to do it.

I have a table that is structured like:

```
CREATE TABLE `batch_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `record_id` (`record_id`)
);
```

The Date field is always YEAR-MONTH-01. Data looks something like:

```
+------+-----------+------------+
|  id  | record_id |   created  |
+------+-----------+------------+
|    1 | 1         | 2019-01-01 |
|    2 | 2         | 2019-01-01 |
|    3 | 3         | 2019-01-01 |
|    4 | 1         | 2019-02-01 |
|    5 | 2         | 2019-02-01 |
|    6 | 1         | 2019-03-01 |
|    7 | 3         | 2019-03-01 |
|    8 | 1         | 2019-04-01 |
|    9 | 2         | 2019-04-01 |
+------+-----------+------------+
```

So what I'm trying to do, with out having to create a looping script, is find the  AVG number of sequential months for each record. Example with the data above would be:

```
Record_id 1 would have a avg of 4 months.
Record_id 2 would be 1.5
Record_id 3 would be 1
```

I can write a script to iterate through all the records. I just would rather avoid that.

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x? This seems easy in 8.x.

Comment: @Pyramanci . . . By any chance, do you have other information, such as the gaps are no longer than one month?

Comment: @TheImpaler it's 5.5.60-MariaDB on a CentOS 7.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the gaps could be more then a month. The squence and gaps could easily go on for more then a year.

Comment: This is a gap and island problem where the use of `LEAD()`, `LAG()`, or `ROW_NUMBER()` could be useful. Unfortunately they are not available on MySQL 5.x

Comment: @TheImpaler do you have an example? It would take a little prep work, but I am not opposed to upgrading the database version. I would just end up doing it sooner then i planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You simply need an enumeration of the rows for this to work.  In MySQL 8+, you would use `row_number()` but you can use a global enumeration here:

```
select record_id, min(created) as min_created, max(created) as max_created, count(*) as num_months
from (select bi.*, (created - interval n month) as grp
      from (select bi.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as n  -- generate some numbers
            from batch_item bi cross join
                 (select @rn := 0) params
            order by bi.record_id, bi.month
           ) bi
      ) bi
group by record_id, grp;
```

Note that when using `row_number()`, you would normally `partition by record_id`.  However that is not necessary, if the numbers are created in the correct sequence.

The above query gets the islands.  For  your final results, you need one more level of aggregation:

```
select record_id, avg(num_months)
from (select record_id, min(created) as min_created, max(created) as max_created, count(*) as num_months
      from (select bi.*, (created - interval n month) as grp
            from (select bi.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as n  -- generate some numbers
                  from batch_item bi cross join
                       (select @rn := 0) params
                  order by bi.record_id, bi.month
                 ) bi
            ) bi
      group by record_id, grp
     ) bi
group by record_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tested solution. It should work in MySQL 8.x with minor tweaks, since I don't remember date arithmetic in MySQL:

```
with
a as ( -- the last row of each island
  select *
  from batch_item
  where lead(created) over(partition by record_id order by created) is null
     or lead(created) over(partition by record_id order by created) 
    > created + 1 month -- Fix the date arithmetic here!
),
e as ( -- each row, now with the last row of its island
  select b.id, b.record_id, min(a.last_created) as end_created
  from batch_item b
  join a on b.record_id = a.record_id and b.created <= a.created
  group by b.id, b.record_id
),
m as ( -- each island with the number of months it has
  select
    record_id, end_created, count(*) as months
  from e
  group by record_id, end_created
)
select -- the average length of islands for each record_id
  record_id, avg(months) as avg_months
from m
group by record_id
```